# problem debugging with Code::Blocks on Ubuntu using gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, ubuntu, gdb, codeblocks

I just started programming C++, first in ms Visual c++, then in Code::Blocks.

The problem is that on my computer, running Ubuntu, Code::Blocks "out of the box" does not debug, even the default "hello world", it just skips all breakpoints and finishes the program.

I have a virtualized Windows machine using Sun's VirtualBox and the window's Code::Blocks that I put there runs great "out of the box"!.

the program on ubuntu, shows this when I try to debug: ***Can't find member of namespace, class, struct, or union named "a/b/c"*** where a/b/c is the path to where the program I am building is.

that's what appears on the debugger log:

---

Building to ensure sources are up-to-date  
Build succeeded  
Selecting target: 
Debug  
Adding source dir: /home/arnau/Documents/UNI/compus/Code::Blocks/opo/  
Adding source dir: /home/arnau/Documents/UNI/compus/Code::Blocks/opo/  
Adding file: bin/Debug/opo  
Starting debugger: 
done  
Registered new type: wxString  
Registered new type: STL String  
Registered new type: STL Vector  
Setting breakpoints  
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb 6.8-debian

Can't find member of namespace, class, struct, or union named "/home/arnau/Documents/UNI/compus/Code::Blocks/opo/main.cpp:8"  
Hint: try '"/home/arnau/Documents/UNI/compus/Code::Blocks/opo/main.cpp:8 or '"/home/arnau/Documents/UNI/compus/Code::Blocks/opo/main.cpp:8  
(Note leading single quote.)  
Program exited normally.  
Debugger finished with status 0

---

Thank you for your time, I really appreciate that.

Arnau, from Barcelona

Answer (score 4):

Your naming of the source directory: `.../Code::Blocks/...` is most unfortunate.

While UNIX allows any character in a filename, except `'/'` and `NUL`, it is unwise to use `':'`, because that is a `PATH` separator, and you would not be able to add e.g. `/home/arnau/Documents/UNI/compus/Code::Blocks/opo` to your `PATH`.

In `GDB` there are two additional meanings of `':'` -- the separator between file name and line number (or function name), *and* `'::'` as a scope indicator (required for handling `C++`).

Summary: rename `"Code::Blocks"` directory to `codeblocks`, and live happily ever after.